# Record route ignoted while sending ack

Tags: sip, pjsip

I have a strange problem where pjsip ignores the record route info while sending the ack.  Below are the sip message flow from the logs:

```
INVITE sip:+110@xxx.com;transport=tls SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS ipv4.addr:38890;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjdYP6TZrj4w7v8kicC3cBgABBNb47QHH2;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "+558" <sip:+558@xxx.com>;tag=qfc3TEYcpfIBQHVXMOmh.7pyvqgmVdMh
To: sip:+110@xxx.com
Contact: "+558" <sip:+558@xxx.com>
Call-ID: 7FdLGhQ1L5BjAQsUrCPEOB3WbXipRfs1
CSeq: 18162 INVITE
Route: <sip:xxx.com:5061;transport=tls;lr>
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
User-Agent: SecuVOICE BB10 CSE 2.14.0.1 on Z10 10.3.1.2243
Authorization: Digest xxxx
Content-Type: application/x-x509-user-cert
Content-Length:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Max-Forwards: 10
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS ipv4.addr:38890;rport=38890;received=ipv4.addr;branch=z9hG4bKPjdYP6TZrj4w7v8kicC3cBgABBNb47QHH2;alias
Record-Route:<sip:xxx.com:5061;transport=tls;lr;ftag=qfc3TEYcpfIBQHVXMOmh.7pyvqgmVdMh;cookie_=e43.052768f7>
Call-ID: 7FdLGhQ1L5BjAQsUrCPEOB3WbXipRfs1
From: "+558" <sip:+558@xxx.com>;tag=qfc3TEYcpfIBQHVXMOmh.7pyvqgmVdMh
To: <sip:+110@xxx.com>;tag=RuDb.RX-9YD0V.BKh0rpj61-SK-ORE5B
CSeq: 18162 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Contact: "+110" <sip:+110@ipv4.addr:25365>
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=SBC1hJLGTAfp3t2j3HYWIvvgUBsC1RpJ
Content-Length: 27

ACK sip:+110@ipv4.addr:25365 SIP/2.0 
"+110" <sip:+110@ipv4.addr:25365>
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS ipv4.addr:38890;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjkp-dUZmmgpXNWrZHe2ykqvrr9CgRvlm2;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "+558" <sip:+558@xxx.com>;tag=qfc3TEYcpfIBQHVXMOmh.7pyvqgmVdMh
To: sip:+110@xxx.com;tag=RuDb.RX-9YD0V.BKh0rpj61-SK-ORE5B
Call-ID: 7FdLGhQ1L5BjAQsUrCPEOB3WbXipRfs1
CSeq: 18162 ACK
Route: <sip:xxx.com:5061;transport=tls;lr;ftag=qfc3TEYcpfIBQHVXMOmh.7pyvqgmVdMh;cookie_=e43.052768f7>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   709
```

Looking at the record route from 200 OK, I expected the ACK to look like
    ACK sip:+110@ipv4.addr:25365;transport=tls;lr SIP/2.0

Why pjsip is ignoring the transport uri parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Received Record-Route are copied as Route in a new outgoing request within the dialog.

The exception is if the Record-Route URI does not carry a ";lr" parameter. This is the backward compatible behaviour with [RFC 2543](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2543)

The Request URI of the outgoing request is set to the received Contact header.

See [RFC 3261 Section 12.2.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-12.2.1.1)

> The UAC uses the remote target and route set to build the
> Request-URI    and Route header field of the request.
>
> If the route set is empty, the UAC MUST place the remote target URI
> into the Request-URI.  The UAC MUST NOT add a Route header field to
> the request.
>
> If the route set is not empty, and the first URI in the route set
> contains the lr parameter (see Section 19.1.1), the UAC MUST place
> the remote target URI into the Request-URI and MUST include a Route
> header field containing the route set values in order, including all
> parameters.
>
> If the route set is not empty, and its first URI does not contain
> the    lr parameter, the UAC MUST place the first URI from the route
> set    into the Request-URI, stripping any parameters that are not
> allowed    in a Request-URI.  The UAC MUST add a Route header field
> containing    the remainder of the route set values in order,
> including all    parameters.  The UAC MUST then place the remote
> target URI into the    Route header field as the last value.

The route set is either pre-configured, or learned through the Record-Route.

Target URI is updated when receiving a Contact header from the other party.

Comment: What can be done so that the ACK also adds the transport=tls?

Comment: Add it in the URI of the Contact in the 200 OK.... but I'm not sure it will make a difference, since the message will the sent based on the first Route URI (loose router).

Comment: Will removing ";lr" from initial INVITE will help?

Comment: @BTRNaidu, not sure if that will cause the effect that you desire. Certainly it will mean that you're expecting an RFC2543 infrastructure, instead of an RFC3261. And that will probably cause the request to be handled differently or not at all.

Comment: @BTRNaidu, in any case, I'm not sure what is the unexpected behaviour that you are experiencing. As I said, even though the Request-URI does not contain the transport parameter, since you have a loose Route header, the request should be sent to the first Route header URI, which does contain the transport parameter. The Request URI doesn't matter in the presence of a loose router.